# Integrating a third-party API in to WordPress website issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, rest

I am having a little trouble with integrating a Rest Based API in to my existing WordPress website. The API front-end is made up of PHP, HTML and JQuery code.

I have uploaded the files within the API zip folder to my web server and I have managed to successfully connect up the API. I can see requests to the API are being made successfully which is great.

However, from the front-end of my WordPress, I am including the "index.php" file of my API in to my WordPress website through the use of "Insert PHP" plug-in.

When I attempt to the complete the form fields and then click the Submit button, a conditional result should be shown after a request has been made through to the API.

Instead, I am receiving the following error (Taken from the Console within the Google Chrome Console.

```
VM78:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at buildResults (availability.js:142)
    at Object.success (availability.js:122)
    at fire (jquery.js:2913)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3025)
    at done (jquery.js:7400)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:7822)
```

I have correctly enqueued the JS files in my functions.php file of my theme. I have also tried creating a WordPress custom page template file and after integrating the API in to the custom page, the API checker is working perfect.

However, when I integrate the API checker in to my website homepage (Through using a PHP Include) the above JQuery error is thrown.

Just wondering if anyone has any potential ideas with how I could go around this? I know that generally speaking the above error suggests that HTML is being returned when Javascript should be expected.

But I am a little lost with what other steps I should take to get the API checker successfully integrated on to my WordPress homepage. The reason I require the API checker to display on my homepage is because I am using Visual Composer to tailor a design around the API based checker.

So unfortunately, I'm not really in a position to where I want to rely on a custom page template as I require to be able to use the Visual Composer plug-in to draft a design around the API checker.

Any solutions will be welcomed! :-)
Thanks,
- Josh.

-- Associated JS Code --

```
// Validates form input and sends the availability request.
function checkRequest() {

    // Reset all form values and hide results
    resetAllValues();
    $('#results').hide();
    $('#addressDiv').hide();
    loadingTimer('#searchButton', true);

    // Get checker type radio selection
    var action = $('input[name=action]:radio:checked').val();
    var errorMessage = '';

    // Remove input validation highlight
    $('.form-control').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('input-highlight');
    });

    if (action == 'cli_checker') {

        // Validate cli
        var cli = $('#cliInput').val();
        cli = cli.replace(/\+|\(|\)|\-|\s/gi, '');
        if (/^0[0-9]{9,15}$/.test(cli)) {

            // Show results loading
            $('#results').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#statusTbl').show();
            $('#availableProducts').show();

            // Send availability request
            availabilityRequest(cli);
        }
        else {

            // Display validation error dialog
            errorMessage = 'Telephone number is invalid.';
            $('#cliInput').addClass('input-highlight');
            displayValidationErrorDialog(errorMessage);
        }
    }
    else {

        // Validate postcode
        var postcode = $('#postcodeInput').val();
        postcode = postcode.replace(/\+|\(|\)|\-|\s/gi, '');
        if (validatePostcode(postcode)) {

            // Send address search request
            addressRequest(postcode);
        }
        else {

            // Display validation error dialog
            errorMessage = 'Postcode is invalid.';
            $('#postcodeInput').addClass('input-highlight');
            displayValidationErrorDialog(errorMessage);
        }
    }
}

// Checks if a string is a valid postcode.
function validatePostcode(postcode) {

    var postcode = $('#postcodeInput').val();
    postcode = postcode.replace(/\+|\(|\)|\-|\s/gi, '');
    if (/^[A-Za-z]{1,2}(\d{1,2}|[I])[A-Za-z]? ?\d[A-Za-z]{2}$/.test(postcode))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

// Display validation error message in dialog box.
function displayValidationErrorDialog(errorMessage) {

    if (errorMessage.length > 0) {
        var dialog = $('#console-dialog');
        dialog.find('.modal-title').html('Some problems occured...');
        message = '<p>Some information was entered incorrectly. The incorrect fields are listed below, and have been outlined in <span style="color:blue">blue</span> on the page.</p>';
        message += '<p>' + errorMessage + '</p>';
        dialog.find('.modal-body').html(message);
        dialog.modal('show');
    }
}

// Sets the selected text input field.
function changeInputSelection(buttonId) {

    $('.form-control').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == buttonId + 'Input') {
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
}

// Sets the selected radio input.
function changeCheckerRadio(buttonId) {

    $('.form-control').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('id') != buttonId + 'Input') {
            $(this).removeClass('input-highlight');
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });

    $('#type_phone').prop('checked', (buttonId == 'cli'));
    $('#type_postcode').prop('checked', (buttonId != 'cli'));
}

// Requests availability for a postcode or phone number.
function availabilityRequest(cli) {

    // Send AJAX request for availability 
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '?action=availability-cli',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {
            cli: cli,
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#resultsTitle').html(cli);
            buildResults(result);
            loadingTimer('#searchButton', false);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            showErrorMessage(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
}

// Displays API exception messages.
function showErrorMessage(message) {
    // Display error message
    $('#errorText').html('<p class=\'alert alert-error\'>' + message + '</p>');
    $('#errorText').show();
}

// Updates the product availability results table with the API response.
function buildResults(jsonString) {

    // Parse availability results into object
    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);

    // Display End Request information
    $('#status').html(result.endrequest.status);
    $('#message').html(result.endrequest.message);
    $('#exCode').html(result.endrequest_code);
    $('#exName').html(result.endrequest_name);

    // Loop through product availability results
    for (var i = 0; i < result.products.length; i++) {

        // Get product availability
        var product = result.products[i];
        var availability = (product.availability == true) ? 'Available' : 'Not Available';
        var fetchdata = null;
        if (product.likely_down_speed != null)
            fetchdata = product.likely_down_speed.toFixed(1);
        if (product.likely_up_speed != null)
            fetchdata = fetchdata + ' (' + product.likely_up_speed.toFixed(1) + ')';
        if (fetchdata == null)
            fetchdata = 'Not Available';

        // Update results table
        if (product.name == 'Product One') {
            $('#productoneAvail').html(availability);
            $('#productone').html(fetchdata);
        }
        else if (product.name == 'Product Two') {
            $('#producttwoAvail').html(availability);
            $('#producttwo').html(fetchdata);
        }
        else if (product.name == 'Product Three') {
            $('#productthreeAvail').html(availability);
            $('#productthree').html(fetchdata);
        }
        else if (product.name == 'Product Four') {
            $('#productfourAvail').html(availability);
            $('#productfour').html(fetchdata);
        }
        else if (product.name == 'Product Five') {
            $('#productfiveAvail').html(availability);
            $('#productfive').html(fetchdata);
        }
        else if (product.name == 'Product Six') {
            $('#productsixAvail').html(availability);
            $('#productsix').html(fetchdata);
        }
        else if (product.name == 'Product Seven') {
            $('#productsevenAvail').html(availability);
            $('#productseven').html(fetchdata);
        }
    }
}

// Requests addresses by postcode.
function addressRequest(postcode) {

    // Send AJAX request for address search by postcode
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '?action=address-search',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {
            postcode: postcode
        },
        success: function (result) {
            buildAddressResults(result);
            $('#addressDiv').fadeIn('slow');
            loadingTimer('#searchButton', false);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            showErrorMessage(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
}

// Builds the address search results table from the API response.
function buildAddressResults(jsonString) {

    var addressDiv = document.getElementById('addressDiv');
    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);
    var addressHtml = '';

    // There are no address search results for the postcode
    if (result.addresses.length == 0) {
        $('#errorText').html('<p class=\'alert alert-error\'>No addresses match this postcode.</p>');
        $('#errorText').show();
        return;
    }

    // Build address table
    addressHtml += '<table class="content-table table-curved" style="width:65%; margin:0 auto; margin-top: 12px;">';

    // Loop through address results
    for (var i = 0; i < result.addresses.length; i++) {

        var address = result.addresses[i];

        // Get address fields
        var subPremises = address.sub_premises === null ? "" : address.sub_premises;
        var premisesName = address.premises_name === null ? "" : address.premises_name;
        var thoroughfareNumber = address.thoroughfare_number === null ? "" : address.thoroughfare_number;
        var thoroughfareName = address.thoroughfare_name === null ? "" : address.thoroughfare_name;
        var locality = address.locality === null ? "" : address.locality;
        var postTown = address.post_town === null ? "" : address.post_town;
        var postcode = address.postcode === null ? "" : address.postcode;
        var districtId = address.district_id === null ? "" : address.district_id;
        var nad_key = address.nad_key === null ? "" : address.nad_key;

        // Construct full address 
        var fullAddress = '';
        if (subPremises != '') { fullAddress += subPremises + ' '; }
        if (premisesName != '') { fullAddress += premisesName + ', '; }
        if (thoroughfareNumber != '') { fullAddress += thoroughfareNumber + ' '; }
        if (thoroughfareName != '') { fullAddress += thoroughfareName + ', '; }
        if (postTown != '') { fullAddress += postTown + ', '; }
        if (postcode != '') { fullAddress += postcode; }

        // Build address result table row
        addressHtml += '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            '<input onclick=\'selectAddress(event)\' type=\'radio\' id=\'addressId' + i + '\' name=\'addressId\' value=\'' + i + '\' />' +
                            '<input type=\'hidden\' id=\'subPremises' + i + '\' name=\'subPremises\' value=\'' + subPremises + '\' />' +
                            '<input type=\'hidden\' id=\'premisesName' + i + '\' name=\'premisesName\' value=\'' + premisesName + '\' />' +
                            '<input type=\'hidden\' id=\'thoroughfareNumber' + i + '\' name=\'thoroughfareNumber\' value=\'' + thoroughfareNumber + '\' />' +
                            '<input type=\'hidden\' id=\'thoroughfareName' + i + '\' name=\'thoroughfareName\' value=\'' + thoroughfareName + '\' />' +
                            '<input type=\'hidden\' id=\'postTown' + i + '\' name=\'postTown\' value=\'' + postTown + '\' />' +
                            '<input type=\'hidden\' id=\'postcode' + i + '\' name=\'postcode\' value=\'' + postcode + '\' />' +
                            '<input type=\'hidden\' id=\'districtId' + i + '\' name=\'districtId\' value=\'' + districtId + '\' />' +
                            '<input type=\'hidden\' id=\'nad_key' + i + '\' name=\'nad_key\' value=\'' + nad_key + '\' />' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                                '<label id=\'addressLabel' + i + '\' for=\'addressId' + i + '\'>' + fullAddress + '</label>' +
                            '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';
    }

    // None of the above addresses - search by postcode input
    addressHtml += '<tr>' +
                        '<td className=\'table\'>' +
                        '<input onclick=\'selectAddress(event)\' type=\'radio\' id=\'addressId-1\' name=\'addressId\' value=\'-1\' />' +
                        '<td className=\'table\'>' +
                            '<label for=\'addressId-1\'>None of the above</label>' +
                        '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
    addressHtml += '</table>';
    addressDiv.innerHTML = addressHtml;
}

// Select address event handler.
function selectAddress(event) {

    // Get the targetnode that fired the event
    var target = $(event.target);

    // Get the selected address
    var addressId = target.val();

    // Show results loading
    $('#addressDiv').hide();
    $('#statusTbl').show();
    $('#availableProducts').show();
    $('#results').fadeIn('slow');
    loadingTimer('#searchButton', true);

    // Send request for availability by exact address
    addressAvailabilityRequest(addressId);
}

// Requests availability for address result table id or by postcode if none is selected.
function addressAvailabilityRequest(addressId) {

    // Check if we need to do a postcode check and exit function
    if (addressId == -1) {
        var postcode = $('#postcodeInput').val();
        availabilityRequest(postcode);
        return;
    }

    // Address has been selected from results table
    if (addressId != '') {

        // Get address fields from hidden form input
        subPremises = document.getElementById('subPremises' + addressId).value;
        premisesName = document.getElementById('premisesName' + addressId).value;
        thoroughfareNumber = document.getElementById('thoroughfareNumber' + addressId).value;
        thoroughfareName = document.getElementById('thoroughfareName' + addressId).value;
        postTown = document.getElementById('postTown' + addressId).value;
        postcode = document.getElementById('postcode' + addressId).value;
        districtId = document.getElementById('districtId' + addressId).value;
        nad_key = document.getElementById('nad_key' + addressId).value;

        // Construct API request URL
        var address = {
            sub_premises: subPremises,
            premises_name: premisesName,
            thoroughfare_number: thoroughfareNumber,
            thoroughfare_name: thoroughfareName,
            post_town: postTown,
            postcode: postcode,
            district_id: districtId,
            nad_key: nad_key
        };

        var data = {
            address: JSON.stringify(address)
        }

        // Send AJAX request for availability for specified address
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '?action=availability-exact',
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#resultsTitle').html($('#addressLabel' + addressId).html());
                buildResults(result);
                loadingTimer('#searchButton', false);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                showErrorMessage(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}

// Sets search button loading state.
function loadingTimer(targetNode, start) {

    if (start) {
        $(targetNode).html('Searching...');
    }
    else {
        $(targetNode).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search');
    }
}

// Resets all search results.
function resetAllValues() {

    var loadingImg = "<img src='eligibility/images/spinner.gif' alt='checking' />";

    // Reset error text
    $('#errorText').hide();

    // Reset address
    $('#addressDiv').html('');

    // Reset title
    $('#resultsTitle').html('');

    // Reset all elements to loading
    $('#status').html(loadingImg);
    $('#message').html(loadingImg);
    $('#exCode').html(loadingImg);
    $('#exName').html(loadingImg);

    $('#productoneAvail').html(loadingImg);
    $('#producttwoAvail').html(loadingImg);
    $('#productthreeAvail').html(loadingImg);
    $('#productfourAvail').html(loadingImg);
    $('#productfiveAvail').html(loadingImg);
    $('#productsixAvail').html(loadingImg);
    $('#productsevenAvail').html(loadingImg);

    $('#productone').html(loadingImg);
    $('#producttwo').html(loadingImg);
    $('#productthree').html(loadingImg);
    $('#productfour').html(loadingImg);
    $('#productfive').html(loadingImg);
    $('#productsix').html(loadingImg);
    $('#productseven').html(loadingImg);

}
```

Comment: Please also add the js source code causing error for reference

Comment: That error means that either HTML or XML is being returned from the endpoint you're calling, not JSON as you're expecting. Check the network tab of the console to see what the exact response is. Usually it's an error message in a HTML page when this error occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate responses. Much appreciated! I will grab the JS and will paste it on to here in a moments time. As for the advice regarding the Network tab, I have had a quick look and all the responses I am seeing in here are under the status code of 200. I am not seeing any 404's.

Comment: JS code has been added - Apologies for the double comment.

Comment: I've fixed it! It turns out that even all the status codes on the Network tab was showing as OK. However, after watching the API checker make an API call, I noticed the path that was being used to make an API was actually incorrect. I've modified the path in my JS file to where API calls should be made to - Everything works now :-)